# Tkinter Get Solution Syntax Fit To Another Python Program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to 'get' the newIPEntry and the newLocationEntry variables in my Python with Tkinter program, however I am faced with the error you see below. I have already searched here as I was writing this question, to get the answer after pulling my hair out from frustration of trying to figure it out by myself and searching for a solution for the last couple of days. I found the solution, however, I do not know how to fit the syntax of that solution([Getters in python, tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62914713/getters-in-python-tkinter)) into my current program partly presented here. I do not know how to proceed to take what I have already written and rewrite it to be similar to the solution I have linked.

```
def fixEntries(thisKVM, newIP, newLocation):

 newIP = newIPEntry.get(newIPEntry)
 newLocation = newLocationEntry.get(newLocationEntry)

 a_file = open("kvmIPDefs.py", "r")
 ipUpdate = a_file.readlines()
 ipUpdate[thisKvm] = "kvm"+ thisKVM + "IP = \'" + newIP + "\'\n"

 a_file = open("kvmIPDefs.py", "w")
 a_file.writelines(ipUpdate)
 a_file.close()

 a_file = open("kvmLocDefs.py", "r")
 locUpdate = a_file.readlines()
 locUpdate[thisKvm] = "kvm"+ thisKVM + "Loc = \'" + newLocation + "\'\n"

 a_file = open("kvmLocDefs.py", "w")
 a_file.writelines(locUpdate)
 a_file.close()

def editKVM(self):
 editor = Tk()
 thisKVM = self
 editor.title('Edit KVM' + thisKVM)
 editor.geometry("200x150")
 
 global newIPEntry 
 global newLocationEntry
 newIPEntry = StringVar()
 newLocationEntry = StringVar()

 frame = LabelFrame(editor, text="", padx=5, pady=5)
 frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
 
 newIPLabel = Label(frame, text="NEW IP", font=("Times", 12, "bold")).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
 newIPEntry = Entry(frame, textvariable=newIPEntry).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
 
 newLocationLabel = Label(frame, text="NEW LOCATION", font=("Times", 12, "bold")).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
 newLocationEntry = Entry(frame, textvariable=newLocationEntry).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

 editButton = Button(frame, text="EDIT", font=("Times", 12), padx=1, command=lambda: fixEntries(thisKVM, newIPEntry, newLocationEntry)).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4, ipadx=30)
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your `Entry` and other widgets should be *"put on the screen"*, on a separate line, like.

```
newIPEntry = Entry(frame, textvariable=newIPEntry)
newIPEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Why? Because `newIPEntry = Entry(...).grid(...)` returns `None`. When you call `get()` method or any other methods on `newIPEntry`, your saying `newIPEntry = Entry(....).grid(...).get()` which does not exist. So you have to `grid()` it in a separate line.

And I recommend changing your `textvariable=newIPEntry` of `Entry` to something else, or change the variable name to something else and then `get()` would work perfectly, but not other methods like `insert()` or `delete()`.

Hope you got your doubts cleared, do let me know if any errors.

Cheers

Comment: This was it as suggested. Thank you.

Comment: done. Site wouldn't let me mark the answer for some strange reason. Answer came in too hot, I guess.

Comment: How about now? is it back? My computer just woke up.

Comment: @davidc Yes its fine, now   thanks

Comment: Excellent . . . .